# Not getting output data in recycler view in java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to display data in my recycler view in java. But I am not able to display data in my recycler view. Where am I wrong. I have no idea where I have gone wrong. Please help. This is my adapter class.

```
public class ListAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter1.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModels;

    public ListAdapter1(Context context, List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.supermarketModels = supermarketModels;
    }


    @NonNull
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    @Override
    public ListAdapter1.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tileslist,null);


        return  new ListAdapter1.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull ListAdapter1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvvegetables.setText(supermarketModels.get(position).getVegetables());
        holder.tvquantity.setText(supermarketModels.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.tvprice.setText(supermarketModels.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.tvexpiry.setText(supermarketModels.get(position).getExpiry());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return supermarketModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvvegetables, tvquantity, tvprice, tvexpiry;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvvegetables = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vegetables);
            tvquantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            tvprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            tvexpiry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expiry);

        }
    }
}
```

This is my main activity class. I am trying to display a sample data in the recycler inside the main activity. Here I am displaying data from model class namely `SupermarketModels`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ListAdapter1 listAdapter;
    List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModelsList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        supermarketModelsList.add(new SupermarketModels(1,"sugar cane","20kg",
                "50rs","31/12/2021"));

        supermarketModelsList.add(new SupermarketModels(2,"sugar cane","20kg",
                "50rs","31/12/2021"));
        supermarketModelsList.add(new SupermarketModels(3 ,"sugar cane","20kg",
                "50rs","31/12/2021"));
        initialization();

        setadapter(supermarketModelsList);



    }

    private void initialization(){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    }

    private void setadapter(List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModels){

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter1(this, supermarketModels);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    }
}
```

This is my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
       android:background="@color/white"


       />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maintoolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"


            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is your error message

Comment: Do you have any error message on logcat? And can you also paste your xml file? So that, problem can be searched in more detailed

Comment: View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tileslist,parent,false); Also check your xml file is you are using height Match_parent than change it into wrap content

Comment: try changing         View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tileslist,null);
into 
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tileslist,parent, false);

Also on a sidenote, just make sure to check the text color on the text views :D

Comment: @user16493824 see may edited answer change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and its displayed items , issue is in your main xml layout . Where you are adding toolbar , do `wrap content` of your toolbar layout height then it will display items. like this

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
    android:background="@color/white"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

You shuold set layoutmanager on your recyclerview:
`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context))`
The `LinearLayoutManager` is a vertical/horizontal LayoutManager. You can use `GridLayoutManager` if you want to show data with grid layout

Comment: he did that in `setadapter`